# Can you execute your ready action in the same turn it was readied?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, readied-action, counterspelling

Is it possible for a spellcaster to ready a fireball when he is out of view, move into line of sight and release it in the same turn , without giving the opposing spellcaster the chance to counterspell it since he didn't see it being cast?

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate because I believe [the linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116751) asks effectively the same thing as your own. If you feel this is not the case feel free to [edit] your question to explain why; your question can always be reopened. That all said, hello and welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and you can always drop a comment or visit the [help] for further guidance. Best of luck and happy gaming!